# Get data from generic list between some alphabet

Tags: generic-list, alphabet

I have one generic list , from which I want to get those items only which are starting between some alphabets.

Supoose I have listitems like ABC,DEF,Zebra,Important,Check,Jump

From this I want to get listitem which starts from alphabet between A to  C

This should return ABC,Check only..

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List stringlist= new List() {"ABC","BCD", "CDE","DEF","EFG","PQR","IJK","QRS","XYZ"};

List temp=stringlist.FindAll(s=>Enumerable.Range(**65,3**).Contains(s.toUpper()[0]));

change the range as per your requirement.